# How to query "most recent" values from multiple time ordered tables?

Tags: sql, time-series

I'd like to know what facilities there are for a pretty common query:
Given, say, 2 tables containing time ordered data, I would like to get results containing most recent values as time rolls forward.

To be specific, say I have two tables, trades and quotes. They look like this:

```
trades: timestamp, symbol, price
quotes: timestamp, symbol, bid, offer
```

I would like to a resulting table which looks like this:

```
resultset: timestamp, symbol, price, bid, offer
```

Notice that each instance in time, I want the trade and the most recent quote at the time of the trade.

Normally this query requires  (I believe) three self joins -- pretty nasty for someone who doesn't do sql on a daily basis. Much worse I'm sure if I need to include information from 5 or 6 other tables as well.

*Are there variants or extensions of sql which make such queries simpler?*

I've read about a time-series extension to sql and in recent years there have been all kinds of updates to standard sql as well as vendor specific versions.

I'm trying to familiarize myself with what is out there in the standard, industry or even academia which improves how such ordered data is queried.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
    select q.timestamp, q.symbol, t.price, q.bid, q.offer
    from trades t
    inner join quotes q
    on t.timestamp = q.timestamp and t.symbol = q.symbol
    where ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY q.timestamp, q.symbol ORDER BY q.timestamp DESC) = 1
```